# AG-grid: Cell Editors

Tags: angular, ag-grid

`ag-grid` has a property `stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus`. I created my own cell editor by providing a cell editor component.

Is there an equivalent property or method to property `stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus` when using a custom cell editor component?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please share your code so we can better understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such an option for custom cell renderers. However, you could detect focusOut yourself and call stopEditing() from the ICellEditorParams interface.

```
interface ICellEditorParams {
    ...
    // Callback to tell grid to stop editing the current cell. pass 'false' to prevent navigation moving
    // to the next cell if grid property enterMovesDownAfterEdit=true
    stopEditing: (suppressNavigateAfterEdit?: boolean)=>void;
    ...
}
```